# TYPO3: How can I translate content elements within articles for news?

Tags: multilingual, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news

I am using the news extension: news and have enabled the content element rendering for my articles via extension setup (Use content element relation). This works great and redacteurs can use content elements in the news articles, too.

Furthermore I have localized and translated all the articles So if I switch the language in frontend then the translated articles will show up, but the content elements within this translated articles are still in the default language and not translated. So it seems that the translation of the content elements is not working for me.

For this reason I have checked the language of the content elements within the translated articles again, but the language settings of this content elements looks right:

[image]

I don't know what I am doing wrong and hope you can help me?

System:

- TYPO3 7.6.12
- news 4.3.0

**UPDATE**

I have found the following ticket: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/67905 and I have tried a updated version of the typoscript in this ticket, but it don't work for me, but maybe is this right way to get the content elements translated, too. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution :). News use RECORDS for content element rendering. So I have to add some typoscript.

**setup.txt or setup area**

```
config {
    sys_language_overlay = 1
}
```