# Translation of content elements in tx_news shows default language

Tags: typo3, tx-news

#### Environment:

- TYPO3: 8LTS
- News: 6.3.0 (also checked with 7.x)
- News List View (Page) is translated
- News Detail View (Page) is translated
- News Record translated

#### Problem:

When i visit the page on language UID 1 the news record itself is translated (For example `headline`). In the Detail view we render the content element. This is always shown in the default language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem could be fixed by switching `sys_language_overlay` from `0` to `1`

```
config {
    sys_language_mode = content_fallback
    sys_language_overlay = 1
}
```

To prevent that the content elements are hidden by default you could also set

```
TCEMAIN.table.tt_content {
    disablePrependAtCopy = 1
    disableHideAtCopy = 1
}
```

Comment: I had the same issue some time ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40550695/typo3-how-can-i-translate-content-elements-within-articles-for-news. But it could leads to some trouble too, for example if you load your footer data of the news detail page with typoscript, like:<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="helper.dynamicContent" data="{pageUid:'{settings.footerDataId}',colPos:'10'}"/>. Then sys_language_overlay = 1 will cause that the default footer data is loaded, but not the translated footer data. In my case I had to add the sys_language_uid to my dynamic content helper.

Comment: So if you use content objects for rendering (https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Content/Index.html) and enable sys_lanugage_overlay = 1, then you have to be aware that you also add sys_language_uid clause to the content object rendering.