# TYPO3 ext form - How to change the language of a content element 'text'?

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-8.7.x

I'm using the extension form and one of the elements is a content element of type 'text' with the uid 8. I've created the 'content element' in my storage folder and it has some plain text with links.

I'v also setup language files xlf to make changes to the other form elements. But how can I change the language of this 'content element' type text?

If I make a translation of the storage folder [2] ... I can make a translation of the 'content element' [8] itself ... but the new 'content element' in the new language also has a new uid [15].

And in the form the 'content element' points to [8].

How can I solve this that I have a text (with links) and make a language switch?

I tried to make the switch in the xlf ... but that didn't work:

```
<trans-unit id="BasicContactForm.element.contentelement-1.properties.contentElementUid" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
    <source>8</source>
    <target>15</target>
</trans-unit>
```

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50871787/translation-of-content-elements-in-tx-news-shows-default-language/50871788#50871788

Comment: I tried ... but I didn't see any changes. What is it supposed to do?